# Understanding Median Value in the BoxPlot for Profit/Loss Made in Stock Market?

Tags: median

I have multiple stocks and I took the PROFIT/LOSS for the stocks and plotted it using a box plot (using python seaborn library). Interestingly the median is seen as 0. So does this means that most of stock is making no-profit/no-loss?

I do know that I am actually making around 40K loss, so this baffles me. What does this mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A zero median *roughly* means that 50% of your data values are positive and 50% of the values are negative. So one half of your stocks gives profit, the other half gives a loss.

This does not contradict the fact that you loose money in total. It is possible that the total amount of loss is bigger then the total amount of profit.

Simple example: suppose you have 4 stocks. Suppose the profits/losses are $-2000$, $-100$, $100$, $500$. Then you loose $1500$ dollars, even though 50% of the stock gives profits and the other 50% gives losses.